# Sitecore Pipeline (indexing.filterIndex.inbound) not being called

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I am trying to create a Lucene index in Sitecore 8.x of items that are visible to unauthenticated users (extranet\Anonymous). In order to do this I am trying to use the indexing.filterIndex.inbound pipeline.

I have tried writing a custom pipeline that returns false if the item cannot be read as extranet\Anonymous:

```
    public class ApplyInboundIndexAccessFilter : InboundIndexFilterProcessor
{
    public override void Process(InboundIndexFilterArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.IndexableToIndex as SitecoreIndexableItem;
        var anonymousUser = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName("extranet\\anonymous", false);

        if (!item.Item.Security.CanRead(anonymousUser))
        {
            args.IsExcluded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

but at no time does this pipeline get invoked.

I have added my config (tried it with the default, before, after, with the default removed)

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <indexing.filterIndex.inbound>
                <processor type="MyApplication.Site.Features.ContentSearch.IndexFilters.ApplyInboundIndexAccessFilter, MyApplication.Site">
                    <includedIndexNames hint="list">
                        <indexName>siteSearchIndex_web</indexName>
                    </includedIndexNames>
                    <excludedIndexNames hint="list">
                        <indexName>siteSearchIndex_master</indexName>
                    </excludedIndexNames>
                </processor>
            </indexing.filterIndex.inbound>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Am I right in assuming that this should be called on indexing, if not, when?

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Code and configurations look good, Are you seeing anything in the logs?

Comment: There was a problem with the includedIndexNames and excludedIndexNames causing an exception to be thrown, hence the processor not being called. I am now looking at how I can correctly set the inclusion/exclusion. The hint was as per an example that I found online, but clearly it needs to be revised for my use-case.